# starting android activity from a thread's inside thread.

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This code is inside MainActivity class.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            }
                       });
                     thread2.start();


             }
          });
          thread1.start();
```

When i run this code nothing happend.

Comment: i have to use two level of threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivity` should be run in the main thread, so if you need to run it from your `thread2`, I'd post it to run in the main thread.

```
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override 
      public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use other threads to work on UI or calling other activities,
You can do it from main UI thread only.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
```

Running other threads means, you are doing some extra tasks simultaneously along with the main thread.